# File access in maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project consisting of 3 subprojects: commons, server and client where the client and the server have a dependency on commons but do not know each other.

In commons I have to create and read/write to/from files but I end up with a AccessControlException: access denied Exception whenever I try to do something with files.

The exception looks like:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "test.txt" "write")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:979)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
```

I get the error even if I execute the following code in commons:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
file.createNewFile();    //write exception
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); //if file would exist it would throw read exception
```

If I execute this code on the client or the server it runs just fine.

The pomfile for the server looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>server</artifactId>
<groupId>my.project</groupId>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.project.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>0.1 Alpha</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.project.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>0.1 Alpha</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
</project>
```

The pomfile for commons looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"><modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>commons</artifactId>
<groupId>my.project.commons</groupId>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Do you have any ideas where the error is or what I'm missing?

Comment: Where you get those exceptions? I think the reason is you try to read file which isn't closed.

Comment: I will add a more detailed description.

Comment: Tip for the future. You better change your question and then write comment. Because I get notification on comment, but there is no notification about changes in question.

Comment: Show your exceptions text.